# In ASP.Net MVC 3, how do indicate that properties of child objects have error while writing a custom model validator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following Model:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Address Address {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
   public string Street {get;set;}
   public string City {get;set}
}
```

I have now created a ModelValidator for which validates Person objects. The ModelValidator has one method to implement:

```
public abstract System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> 
Validate(object container)
```

In this case how do I indicate that an error has occurred for the Address.Street property of the Person object. I have tried setting the ModelValidationResult.MemberName to Address.Street but this is not working?

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it does work.

In the above example, setting the Member property of the Model Validation Error to "Address.City" does highlight the city field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://codingndesign.com/blog/?p=96) for an example of a custom ModelValidator...

It looks like they're making use of the ModelMetadata to handle the property names